# JFileChooser Add different file types in filter

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have a `JFileChooser` and i want to have different options available in the type which will change the extension. The options i want are

- .txt
- .html
- .xml

Right now I have:

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new WritableFileChooser(Model.getSingleton().getOptionsParam().getUserDirectory());

    chooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file)
        {
            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (file.isFile())
            {
                String lcFileName = file.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
                return (lcFileName.endsWith(TXT_FILE_EXTENSION) || lcFileName.endsWith(HTML_FILE_EXTENSION) || lcFileName.endsWith(XML_FILE_EXTENSION)                                          }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription()
        {
            return Constant.messages.getString("file.format.html");
        }
```

But only All files and HTML are available in the file type filter. Ideally, i also want to get rid of the All files options.

Also i have two different format .html's that are to be generated, is there any indicator i can add so that the file chooser is smart enough to know which one i want?

Comment: You should look at Oracle's official tutorial - [How to Use File Choosers - Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters). It provides solutions to both of your problems.

Comment: That didn't help me, it filters what's visible. Not what can be selected from the drop down list. I need multiple filters, not just one. The example on their page shows how to group All Images into a single filter which is not what i want. I want separate filters for each file type and sometimes separate filters for the same file type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @AndrewMcCoist said, the [Oracle Tutorial on Filters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters) is somewhat helpful but i got my answer and solution from this [example](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/add-file-filter-for-jfilechooser-dialog).

```
        chooser .addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF Documents", "pdf"));
        chooser .addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("MS Office Documents", "docx", "xlsx", "pptx"));
        chooser .addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp"));
```